# Adding a ArrayList into a swing ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, jcombobox

I'm building a GUI using the Netbeans in built drag and drop GUI builder and I'm struggling to get a jCombobox to take an arraylist and hoping somebody could point out what I'm doing wrong. Everything I try seems to cause an error and I'm pulling my hair out here trying to get it to work properly.

I've created the comboBox using the following code

```
jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
```

I would really appreciate it if somebody could tell me how to populate the comboBox using my List AvailableVideo

I've included the objects in my main method that initialise:

```
//Created a user object to represent a customer of the streaming service 
User user;

//Initiliased video object
Video video ;


//Create new arraylist using  AvailableVideos
List AvailableVideos = new ArrayList<>();

 //Created CurrentPlaylist object to store a collection of video objects
List<Video> CurrentPlaylist= new ArrayList<>();


MyVideos myVideos = new MyVideos(user);
```

Then in my initComponents I have

```
    public GUI_App() {
     
    initComponents();

    //Call the AddVideos method to add available videos 
    Video.addVideos((ArrayList<Video>) AvailableVideos);
}
```

Below I've included both classes that I'm calling

```
public class MyVideos {
private ArrayList<Video> items;
private int currentItemNumber;
private User user;

public MyVideos(User user) {      
    this.user = user;
    this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    this.currentItemNumber = 0;
}

public MyVideos() {      
    this.user = new User("Intro Account", 1000);
    this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    freebieMedia();   
    this.currentItemNumber = 0;
}

private void freebieMedia(){
    items.add(new Series("Game of Thrones",50,false));
    items.add(new Series("Planet Earth",60,true));
    items.add(new MusicVideo("Losing my religion", 200, "REM"));
    items.add(new Movie("The Last Jedi", 9120, "Rian Johnson"));
}

public User getUser(){
    return user;
}

public int getNumItems() {
    return items.size();
}

public ArrayList<Video> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public Video getMedia(int i) {
    return items.get(i);
}

public void addMedia(Video m){
    if(user.hasSufficientBalance(m)) {
        items.add(m);
        this.user.changeBalance(-m.getPrice());
    }
    System.out.println("added " + m.getTitle());
}
  
public String getScheduleAsString(){
    String rs = "";
    for(Video m: items){
        rs += m.toString() + "\n";
    }
    return rs;
}

public int getTotalDuration(){
    int time = 0;
    for(Video m: items){
        time += m.getDuration();
    }
    return time;
}

public int getTotalCost(){
    int cost = 0;
    for(Video m: items){
        cost += m.getPrice();
    }
    return cost;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String str = "Number of Items:"  + this.getNumItems() + "\t"
            + "Time: " + getTotalDuration()
            + getScheduleAsString();

    return str; 
}


/* A method to add a media item without chargeing user's wallet */    
public void addFreeMedia(Video m){
    items.add(m);
}    /* A method to remove a media item from the playlist */    
public void removeMedia(int i) {
    items.remove(i);
}
}
```

Video Class

```
public abstract class Video {

private int duration;
private String title;

public Video(String name, int minutes) {
    this.title = name;
    this.duration = minutes;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}    

public int getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(int d) {
    this.duration = d;
}

  
@Override
public String toString() {
    DecimalFormat round = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    return  this.getTitle() 
            + ", Duration: " + this.getDuration() + "min, " +
            "Cost: £" + round.format(getPrice());
}

public abstract double getPrice();




/* Convenience method for Part 2 to allow Video objects can be added */
public static void addVideos(ArrayList<Video> v){
    v.add(new Series("Game of Thrones",50,false));
    v.add(new Series("Planet Earth",60,true));
    v.add(new MusicVideo("Losing my religion", 4, "REM"));
    v.add(new Movie("The Last Jedi", 152, "Rian Johnson"));
}
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the videos. 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. Please [edit] the question to add 4 space chars ahead of the closing `}` at the end of the code. 3) Be careful with tags. [tag:swingx] is not only irrelevant to the problem, but has far fewer followers than [tag:swing]! 4) There is a `ListModel` which accepts a `Vector`.

Comment: @Pedro Try simplifying things down for a second. Simply making a String array `String[] videos = {"String1", "String2", "String3"};` and then creating the JComboBox by doing `JComboBox myComboBox = new JComboBox(videos);`

Comment: Start with [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).  You'll then want to become familiar with [`ComboBoxModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html).  My "personal" approach would be to create a custom combobox model which used a `ArrayList` as it's backing data

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"create a custom combobox model which used a `ArrayList`"* Yeah, that's a better approach than to use a `Vector` 'for the convenience'.

Comment: In my opinion, a GUI builder is **not** a good way to learn _Swing_. A GUI builder will **not** generate code that uses the `JCombobBox` [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox-E:A-) that takes an `Object` array parameter. So all you need to do is convert the `ArrayList` to an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-). I recommend you go through the _Swing_ tutorial. (See the comment from _MadProgrammer_)